# Is there a specific scenario where Directory.EnumerateFiles would return 0 results from a directory with hundreds of files?

Tags: c#, wpf, system.io.directory

I'm writing code in a .NET Framework 4.7.2 app and for some reason it's not returning any files when I run this snippet on a populated directory:

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(appDirectory, $"{appName}.*").ToList();
```

The 'appDirectory' is just the path I want to enumerate and inside it are dll and exe files I am looking for (hence the filter on appName).

Now what is particularly strange to me is that I created a test console app where I could run just the method containing this snippet for test purposes and it is returning a list of files as I would expect.  The test app is .NET 7.

The method signature is public static:

```
public static string GetVersionFromExeOrDll(string appDirectory, string appName)
```

The only other relevant information I can think of is in the .NET Framework app, this method is being run a little over a hundred times on 3 different threads, but the threads all access separate data and each loop within the threads are totally separate directories.  When I hit a breakpoint in this method on any of the threads, I see the appropriate 'appDirectory' data and 'appName' data, but when I step through the snippet mentioned above, it is returning 0 files.

Does anyone know what could be going on here?

EDIT1:  Based on comment discussions, I wanted to add some clarifications:

1. I can clearly see a directory containing the files at the given path.  I have full directory permissions to view the files and have confirmed I get the results I expect when running the method on a single test call with the exact same inputs for `appDirectory` and `appName`.
2. The only time I don't get the results I expect is when running the method in a multi-threaded context.  It appears to me that the methods `Directory.EnumerateFiles()` and `Directory.GetFiles()` both have issues when running in a multi-threaded context.  I can't seem to find any documentation about this limitation...

Comment: Why are you using `EnumerateFiles(...).ToList()` instead of just `GetFiles()` ?

Comment: What are the exact values of `appDirectory` and `appName`?

Comment: Please show us a screenshot of the `appDirectory` folder (or the result of `dir <appname>.*`) to prove there are indeed files you are searching.

Comment: @Dai, my understanding is that EnumerateFiles() with a search pattern is more efficient, as it lazy loads data for the search parameter... if there was no search pattern involved it would make more sense to just use GetFiles()

Comment: @Dai, and to be clear, I am performing another .Where() search on the EnumerateFiles() call in the final production code before I call .ToList().... I broke it up into two separate calls for testing to see if the .Where() call had something to do with not getting data returned

Answer (score 1):

The filter `$"{appName}.*"` will find files whose name-without-extension is **exactly** the value of `appName`. So if you only have *.exe and *.dll in that folder you get two files at max returned.

I assume you want files that **start with** `appName`. So you need to add another asterisk:

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(appDirectory, $"{appName}*.*").ToList();
```

Comment: Or just `appName + "*"`, IIRC doing `*.*` or `appName + ".*"` won't match files _without_ any filename extension.

Comment: In "DOS" (cmd.exe) you get extensionless files when you do `dir *.*` I _assume_ that goes directly to the `FindFirstFile` / `FindNextFile` `Win32-API` just as  `EnumerateFiles` does.
But I agree it is not necessary or logic to always use the `*.*` pattern and that `*` is sufficient and also better.

Comment: I am trying to find ONLY appName.exe and appName.dll EXACTLY.  So the extra asterisk shouldn't matter.

Comment: @eerick if you’re after specific file names, why not just use `new FileInfo` and check `.Exists`?

Comment: @eerick ok thank you. Did you find the true reason meanwhile? Could it be that its just an issue of multithtreaded debugging (where the same breakpoint is hit almost simultaneously by two threads? do you dump the result (appPath: appName: result to the console our output window in Debug-build?

Comment: @lidqy, I haven't been able to find an answer.  I do suspect it is somehow multithread related, since I can see the results fine if not on a background thread, but I can't understand what would be blocking it.  I'm not outputting the results, just stepping through code and seeing it returning an empty list when on a background thread.

Comment: @Dai, I wasn't certain I could rely on the files always being in the root/parent folder, but I may need to use that approach since both EnumerateFiles() and GetFiles() seem to fail on background threads...

Comment: @eerick I observed the phenomenon that Yield-Iterators (I assume EnumerateFiles is one) seem empty when you go on the 'Results' in Visual Studio tooltip - but they weren't actually empty when you being enumerated in foreach oder ToList etc. But it was kind of an unstable observation.

Comment: @Dai, well... strangely, checking for the exact file gives me results... it's either something to do wtih multi-threading that those methods don't like, or some folder permissions somehow denying a full search, but still allowing me to see individual files... I sure wish I could find a clear answer as to why those methods don't work, but just checking File.Exists() on the file works fine... if you want to add that comment as an answer, I will go ahead and accept it as the solution

Comment: @lidqy, I understand the results can seem to vary in Visual Studio tooltips, but the actual code handles the data differently if it comes back empty, so it's not just a Visual Studio issue... those functions just aren't returning results for some reason when on background threads